# Form validation with validate.js is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

The validation is not working in the following code. I am using validate.js. Can please anybody point out the problem ?

```
<form id="tf">
    <input type="text" id="q" name="q" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tf").validate({
            rules: {
                q: {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                q: {
                    required: "Done"
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Umm, try adding the `q` class to something?

Comment: The information is not helpful. You need to give more information into what you are doing? The error could be as simple as you not referencing jquery files.

Comment: Have you included `jquery.js`?

Comment: yes i included jquery.js

Comment: Your code is working fine. http://jsfiddle.net/vD8uy/ Please provide your full HTML. Maybe you're missing something essential!

Comment: The code is working. Check if you've added   `jquery.validate.js`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a class, rather than an ID, for validate to work.

```
<input type="text" id="q" class="q" name="q" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding

```
class="required"
```

to the inputs?

Comment: by adding class="required" is start working but still error message is not shown